# How to access subarray key of JSON object in AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a user form which makes an AJAX call which returns a JSON object for me to manipulate dependent on what the user has entered in or not. 
When there are errors (a user has not put anything in an input field for instance) , the input box name is returned along with an error message and stored in an errors array which is then returned in a JSON object. This is because I will then take the input box names, find them in the DOM using jQuery and place a span with the error message after the input boxes which have errors.
The issue I am having is when I loop through the returned errors in the JSON object it doesn't let me access the key for the errors (input names), only the array position (0,1,2,3,4,etc).
Can I access associate array keys in JSON/jQuery objects or am I going wrong somewhere?

Here is my code (I have only included the code which is relevant):

This is the AJAX call return

```
success   :   function(data) {
if(data.errors == 'undefined' && data.errors == null) {                     
    ...
} else {
    jQuery(data.errors).each(function(k, v) {
        var html = "<span class='inputError'>" + v + "</span>";
        var errorSpan = '.signUpInputWrap input[name=' + k + ']';
        ...
    });
}
```

}

So, in there you can see I am trying to use 'k' (which is the input box name returned in the json) so I can access it in the DOM. Instead of using the returned name though it uses array position instead.

Here is the PHP which generates the error array and returns it:

```
$result = $this->validateInput($post);
..
if($result['result'] == true) {
...
} else {
echo json_encode(array('errors' => $result['errors']));
}

private function validateInput($input) {

    $errors = array();
    foreach($input as $key => $inputItem) {         
        if($key == 'sports_instructed' || $key == 'activities_qualified' | $key == 'sports_qualified') {
            continue;
        }
        if(empty($inputItem)) {
            if($key == 'dob' || $key == 'dobMonth' | $key == 'dobYear') {
                $errors['dob'] = "Please ensure all values are entered for date of birth";
                unset($input[$key]);
            }
            $pieces = explode('_', $key);
            foreach($pieces as &$piece) {
                $piece = ucfirst($piece);
            }
            $name = implode(" ", $pieces);
            $errors[$key] = "Please enter a value for " . $name;
        }

    }       
    if(empty($errors)) {
        $result = array('result' => true);
    } else {
        $result = array('result' => false, 'errors' => $errors);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Here is the JSON result (as you can see, the key is the input name that I want to use to grab the element within the loop using jQuery):

```
{"errors":{"first_name":"Please enter a value for First Name","last_name":"Please enter a value for Last Name","telNum":"Please enter a value for TelNum","dob":"Please ensure all values are entered for date of birth","dobMonth":"Please enter a value for DobMonth","address":"Please enter a value for Address","city":"Please enter a value for City","county":"Please enter a value for County","postcode":"Please enter a value for Postcode","password":"Please enter a value for Password","password_confirm":"Please enter a value for Password Confirm"}}
```

Is it possible for me to access associate arrays in Javascrip/jQuery much like I can in PHP? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the content of `$post`?

Comment: What does the JSON result look like?

Comment: added the JSON result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$.each` instead of `$().each`. The latter will try to create a jquery object out of your existing object. But with the first option you can access your object directly

```
$.each(data.errors, function(k, v) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
jQuery.each(data.errors,function(k, v) {
    console.log("Key:" +k + " : Value: " + v);
});
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

`$().each` can use for the DOM objects iteration 
`e.g: $('div').each(function(){
})`

`$.each(obj,function(k,v){})` function can be used to iterate over objects or arrays

```
$.each(data.errors,function(k, v)  {
        var html = "<span class='inputError'>" + v + "</span>";
        var errorSpan = '.signUpInputWrap input[name=' + k + ']';
        ...
    });
```

For reference http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/